# Getting or editing a string from a column in a csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

A row of my column named category looks like this:

```
{"id":342,"name":"Web","slug":"technology/web","position":15,"parent_id":16,"color":6526716,"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/technology/web"}}}}
```

I want to edit this column so only the number next to `"parent_id":**16**` stays in every row of the column, how could I do such a thing ?

I'm trying to get a category feature from this csv file for a data science project and this number represents them.

I was able to read the file and the column with:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"filepath")
category = df.category
```

edit: 
my desired column would be:

```
    category
       15
       11
        1
        3
        5
```

stripping everything but the parent_id numbers as these numbers represent a category like 16 is technology. Also the rows of the column are close to 3800

Comment: Can you post a sample of the desired DF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col1' : [{"id":342,"name":"Web","slug":"technology/web","position":15,"parent_id":16}, 
               {"id":342,"name":"Web","slug":"technology/web","position":15,"parent_id":18}],
     'col2' : ['a', 'b']
    })

pd.concat([df, df['col1'].apply(pd.Series)['parent_id']], axis = 1).drop('col1', axis = 1)
```

Comment: what if I want to edit every row of my df.category like this ?

Comment: You can remove ['parent_id'] and it will create a new column for each key, value pair of your dictionary.

Comment: @dungeon if it solved your issue please mark is as the answer. Thanks!